# Accessing view elements in controller in UI5

Tags: sapui5

When my button is pressed, I want to get in my controller, access my button and change the text to `new text` for example.

The `onClick` event works fine. But I stuck at accessing the view element (`myButton`) from the controller. I know there are threads about this topic, but I couldn't apply any of them. `sap.ui.getCore().byId()` for example didn't work for some reason.

Does anyone got some hints or detailed information about accessing view elements from the controller?

Comment: The button's `onPress` event handler takes an event as an argument. You get a reference to the control via the event argument's `getSource()` method

Comment: Ok I'll try. Thank you!    And how can I access other View elements? Like a textfield which isn't the source of an event?

Comment: Generally, you should not access view controls from the controller (the view should access the controller, not the other way around), but there are cases where it is indeed needed. Use `sap.ui.getCore().byId("someId")` (JSView) or `this.getView().byId("someId")` (XMLView)

Comment: The getSource() method worked :) But sap.ui.getCore().byId("") didn't work for some reason. That's my controller code
`var oButton = sap.ui.getCore().byId("nummernpad_1");`
`oButton.setText("neuer text");`
  `return oButton;` The button id is "nummernpad_1".`
`The button is declared in the view like this.`
`var np_1 = new sap.m.Button(this.createId("nummernpad_1"));`
  `np_1.attachPress(oController.sayHello);`

Comment: Because you used `this.createId("someId")` ;-) See http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/02/14/sapui5-javascript-and-uniqueid-definitions for more info

Answer (score 7):

The IDs of the elements of a view shall be created with the [View.createId(sId)](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.View.html#createId). createId(sId) prefixes the given sId with the ID of the view to create a global ID. With that your sId does only have to be unique inside your view. So you can use something like "button1" without any side effects. `createId("button1")` will return something like *__xmlview1--button1*. If you are using [XMLViews](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1409791afe4747319a3b23a1e2fc7064.html) the id attributes will automatically be converted to global IDs (View.createId() is internally [called by the xml parser](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.34/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/XMLTemplateProcessor.js#L156)).

The pendant to [View.createId(sId)](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.View.html#createId) is [View.byId(sId)](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.View.html#byId). It looks up the the element with the given view-locale ID sId. As a shortcut the Controller brings its own [byId(sId) function](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.html#byId) that [delegates to the views byId() function](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.34/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller.js#L273).

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="view1">
  <Button id="button1" press="onButton1Press" text="show my ID"/>
  <Label id="label1" />
</mvc:View>
```

```js
onButton1Press:function(oEvent){
  var button = oEvent.getSource();
  var label1 = this.byId("label1");
  label1.setText(button.getId()); //Label displays "__xmlview0--button1"
}
```

Example on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/falokeyita/2/edit?html,js,output).

If you have - for some reason - a global ID then you have to use [sap.ui.getCore().byId(sId)](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Core.html#byId) to look up the element.

If you use no views at all or JSViews without createId(), then your IDs will be global.

Answer (score 1):

For the event "press", named for example "onPressMyButton" of the button, you can use:

```js
onPressMyButton: function(oEvent) {

  var idOfMyButton = oEvent.getSource().getId();
  
  var myButton = this.getView().byId(idOfMyButton);

  myButton.setText("New Text");
  
}
```

Or in any part of the controller inside of any function, you can use:

```js
var myButton = this.getView().byId("idOfMyButton");
                                   
myButton.setText("New Text");
```

Comment: `oEvent.getSource()` returns already the instance of the pressed button. So you can shorten the code and remove the extra lookup with `var myButton = oEvent.getSource();` Also there is a shortcut for `this.getView().byId()`: `this.byId()`

Comment: Ty @schnoedel by the tips! I didnt knew the second suggestion, but about the first one makes all sense! Thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

inside view :

```
    var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button("this.createId("myButton")",{

    text:'Click Me',
    press: function(){

      controller: functionName(optional);
    }


});
```

inside Controller try to do like this:

```
  sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("myButton")).getValue();
```

hope this will help you.