# In SAPUI5 can you trigger a Smart Table event from a button click?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to use the built in editing features of a smart table but I want to trigger it from a button which I've placed in the overflow toolbar.

This is the event I want to trigger, https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/events/editToggled

Something like this:

```
onEditPromotionsPressed: function(){
    this.editToggled();
},
```

But `editToggled` is not recognised as a function in my controller. Do I need to add the smart table controls into the controller?

Answer (score 1):

`this.editToggled()` will tell that there is a function `editToggled` in your controller which you obviously don't have

To use `editToggle()`, you should have it in your view first. Something like this:

```
<SmartTable id="table" editToggle="onPress"></SmartTable>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, that gets me part of the way there. Now I am able to call a function via `<SmartTable editToggled="onEditPromotionsPressed" ...` but what I really want is to be able to call `editToggled()` from `onEditPromotionsPressed()`

Comment: You should use `oEvent.getSource()` to get the instance of the pressed button. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134942/sapui5-access-view-elements-in-controller

Comment: How do I access the function from that button? The toggleEdit button is a standard smart table button so I don't know what function to use `oEvent.getSource()` in

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept here. `editToggled` is an event, not a method, it is fired/triggered when stardard smart table button is pressed. You press the button, function `onEditPromotionsPressed()` is called, means you successfully access the function. Now you should write code inside the function to do things. In case you want to access the button itself, use `oEvent.getSource()` inside `onEditPromotionsPressed()` to literally get the `source` where the function is called from. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you can call the smarttable toggle from a different button press by using this function below

fireEditToggled

example:

```
 //Other button to call edit function
    onEditPromotionsPressed: function(){
        this.fireEditToggled();
    },

    on smarttable controller you need to specify function for editToggled event and this will be called through fireEditToggled()
```